# How to remove only one sprite of a group of sprites in a game?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am coding a game with #PhaserJS and I want to delete only one sprite in a group of sprites everytime the player is touched by the AI sprites which decrements the number of lifes by one, so in the create function i have

```
  lifes = game.add.group();
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    j = i + 1;
    life = game.add.sprite(20 * j, 20, 'life');

    lifes.add(life);
  }
  lifes.fixedToCamera = true;
```

Then in the update function I just try to remove one sprite when it collides

```
function hitNinja (ninja, ronins) {
  lifes.kill();
}
```

The problem is that it supress all the group of sprites that is displayed at the top of the screen like in the image bellow

Life x 3

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your example `lifes` is the whole group, so calling `kill()` on it will destroy it along with everything it's in it. If you want to act upon individual elements of the group, you should iterate over them in some way.

```
function hitNinja (ninja, ronins) {
    var children = lifes.getAll();
    children[children.length - 1].kill();
}
```

Keep in mind that `kill()` is a method you'd use if you want to 'revive' the sprite later on; otherwise, `destroy()` might be the saner choice.

[Reference for Phaser.Group](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Group.html#exists).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Kamen i'll probably use this solution in this [pen](https://codepen.io/albator2018/pen/VyGVpQ) first then we'll see, i can't vote on your answer yet because i am under 15 reputation, atm i am not sure i'll accept it as the answer ;)